# Not able to apply formula to the excel spreadsheet using phpexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel in my php code to generate an excel report with a number to spreadsheets but i want to apply formula complete columns in those spreadsheets and i am using the following code but its just applying the same values to the complete column but i want the formula to run and give values depending on the each cell column G of my worksheet, and i want these resulting values in column Q.
Following is the complete code that i am using:

```
<?php 
$dbhost= "localhost"; //your MySQL Server 
$dbuser = "root"; //your MySQL User Name 
$dbpass = "root"; //your MySQL Password 
$dbname = "pyramid"; 
//your MySQL Database Name of which database to use this 
$tablename = "peachtree"; //your MySQL Table Name which one you have to create excel file 
// your mysql query here , we can edit this for your requirement 

$tablename1 = "shipping";
$tablename2 = "embassies";
$tablename3 = "documentprocesses";
$tablename4 = "documentdetails";
$tablename5 = "documents";
$sql = "Select * from $tablename "; 
$sql1= "Select * from $tablename1";
$sql2= "Select * from $tablename2";
$sql3= "Select filter1.docID,
  filter1.salesOrderID,
  IF(filter1.docSource='shipping', 'Shipping', 'Non-Shipping') AS 'Doc Type',
  filter1.countryID,
  DATE(filter1.docTimeStamp) AS 'Date Received',
  IF(filter2.processStartDate IS NULL, 'OPEN',
   DATE(filter2.processStartDate)) AS 'Date Shipped',
  $tablename3.processCode,
  $tablename3.destination,
  $tablename3.processStartDate,
  $tablename4.*,
  filter1.docValue
FROM ( SELECT docID,
    salesOrderID,
    docSource,
    docValue,
    countryID,
    docTimeStamp
  FROM $tablename5
  WHERE DATE(docTimeStamp) <= '2015-03-31' ) AS filter1
JOIN (
SELECT docID,
   processStartDate
FROM $tablename3
WHERE processCode = 'SHPD'
  AND( processStatus <> 'completed'
   OR DATE(processStartDate) > '2015-03-31')
) AS filter2
ON filter1.docID = filter2.docID
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM $tablename3
WHERE DATE(processStartDate) <= '2015-03-31'
AND  processStartDate IS NOT NULL) AS $tablename3
ON $tablename3.docID = filter2.docID
LEFT JOIN $tablename4 ON $tablename4.docID = filter2.docID";
//create  code for connecting to mysql 
$Connect = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) 
or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
//select database 
$Db = @mysql_select_db($dbname, $Connect) 
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
//execute query 
$result = @mysql_query($sql,$Connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
$result1 = @mysql_query($sql1,$Connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno()); 
$result2 = @mysql_query($sql2,$Connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$result3 = @mysql_query($sql3,$Connect) 
or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());  

error_reporting(E_ALL);
 set_time_limit(0);
 ini_set('memory_limit','2500M');
 require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
 $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
 // Set the active Excel worksheet to sheet 0 

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  

// Initialise the Excel row number 

$rowCount = 1;  


//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields  

 $column = 'A';

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result); $i++)  

{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, mysql_field_name($result,$i));
    $column++;
}

//end of adding column names  
//start while loop to get data  

$rowCount = 2;  

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))  

{  
    $column = 'A';

   for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result);$j++)  
    {  
        if(!isset($row[$j]))  

            $value = NULL;  

        elseif ($row[$j] != "")  

            $value = strip_tags($row[$j]);  

        else  

            $value = "";  


        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, $value);
        $column++;
    }  

    $rowCount++;
} 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('peachtree');

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(1);
$rowCount = 1;  


//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields  

 $column = 'A';

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result1); $i++)  

{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, mysql_field_name($result1,$i));
    $column++;
}

//end of adding column names  
//start while loop to get data  

$rowCount = 2;  

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result1))  

{  
    $column = 'A';

   for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result1);$j++)  
    {  
        if(!isset($row[$j]))  

            $value = NULL;  

        elseif ($row[$j] != "")  

            $value = strip_tags($row[$j]);  

        else  

            $value = "";  


        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, $value);
        $column++;
    }  

    $rowCount++;
} 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('shipping');

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(2);
$rowCount = 1;  


//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields  

 $column = 'A';

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result2); $i++)  

{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, mysql_field_name($result2,$i));
    $column++;
}

//end of adding column names  
//start while loop to get data  

$rowCount = 2;  

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result2))  

{  
    $column = 'A';

   for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result2);$j++)  
    {  
        if(!isset($row[$j]))  

            $value = NULL;  

        elseif ($row[$j] != "")  

            $value = strip_tags($row[$j]);  

        else  

            $value = "";  


        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, $value);
        $column++;
    }  

    $rowCount++;
} 
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('embassies');

$objPHPExcel->createSheet();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(3);
$rowCount = 1;  


//start of printing column names as names of MySQL fields  

 $column = 'A';

for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($result3); $i++)  

{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, mysql_field_name($result3,$i));
    $column++;
}
$column = 'Q';
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount,"SOS");
//end of adding column names  
//start while loop to get data  

$rowCount = 2;  

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result3))  

{  
    $column = 'A';

   for($j=0; $j<mysql_num_fields($result3);$j++)  
    {  
        if(!isset($row[$j]))  

            $value = NULL;  

        elseif ($row[$j] != "")  

            $value = strip_tags($row[$j]);  

        else  

            $value = "";  


        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount, $value);
        $column++;

    }
    ***$column = 'Q';

    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($column.$rowCount,'=IF(column="SOS",15,0)');
    $rowCount++;***

}      


$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('documentdata');


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5) 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="results.xls"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); 
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5'); 
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wading through your wall of code

```
=IF(column="SOS",15,0)
```

Doesn't look like a valid Excel formula to me. What is column? If it was an Excel named range, or a cell reference, then it would work; but as it stands it's nothing that would be valid in an Excel formula.

Your formula must be a valid Excel formula

**EDIT**

If you want to set a single cell to a value of 15 or 0 depending on whether any cell in column G contains the value "SOS", then an appropriate MS Excel formula for that would be

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("SOS",G:G, 0)), 0, 15)
```

If you want to do this check on a row by row basis, then you'd set your formula to something like:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue($column.$rowCount,'=IF(G'.$rowCount.'="SOS",15,0)');
```

**EDIT #2**

As a way of debugging, for row #2 (ie cell Q2) that formula should be

```
=IF(G2="SOS",15,0)
```

for row #3 (cell Q3) it should be

```
=IF(G3="SOS",15,0)
```

etc

Do some basic debugging to be sure that your PHP is concatenating the formula value correctly

Comment: Thanks for the reply i am using a condition here that is if the column ie has Column G has a value SOS in it then a value 15 should be set in column Q otherwise zero, but its setting the same value for the whole column and i want the values in Column Q to dependent on the values in column G. @http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-bakerark

Comment: Do you mean that for each row, if G1 contains "SOS" then Q1 should be 15, if G2 contains "SOS" than Q2 should contain 15, if G3 contains "SOS" then Q3 should contain 15..... or do you mean that if "SOS" is found anywhere in any row in column G, then cell Q500 (or whatever cell it is) should contain 15..... is this on a row by row basis, or is it a single check for the entire row?

Comment: Thanks for understanding the problem its a row by row basis. @http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker

Comment: I tried the second code that you shared but its giving an 500 internal error. @http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker